# Can not install julia packages

Tags: julia, julia-pkg

I just installed julia today and I tried to add the images package but it does not work. It does fetching till 100%. Then it stays on fetching for about 4 minutes with nothing happening like this:

```
(@v1.4) pkg> add Images
    Cloning default registries into `C:\Users\Quinten Cabo\.julia`
    Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
    Fetching: [========================================>]  100.0 %
```

And then after 4 minutes I get this error:

```
    Cloning default registries into `C:\Users\Quinten Cabo\.julia`
    Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
ERROR: SystemError: opening file "C:\\Users\\Quinten Cabo\\.julia\\registries\\General\\Registry.toml": No such file or directory
Stacktrace:
 [1] systemerror(::String, ::Int32; extrainfo::Nothing) at .\error.jl:168
 [2] #systemerror#50 at .\error.jl:167 [inlined]
 [3] systemerror at .\error.jl:167 [inlined]
 [4] open(::String; read::Bool, write::Nothing, create::Nothing, truncate::Nothing, append::Nothing) at .\iostream.jl:254
 [5] open(::String, ::String) at .\iostream.jl:310
 [6] open(::typeof(Pkg.TOML.parse), ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at .\io.jl:296
 [7] open at .\io.jl:296 [inlined]
 [8] parsefile at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\ext\TOML\src\TOML.jl:50 [inlined]
 [9] read_registry(::String; cache::Bool) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\Types.jl:974
 [10] read_registry at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\Types.jl:969 [inlined]
 [11] (::Pkg.Types.var"#92#95"{Pkg.Types.Context,String,Pkg.Types.RegistrySpec})(::String) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\Types.jl:946
 [12] mktempdir(::Pkg.Types.var"#92#95"{Pkg.Types.Context,String,Pkg.Types.RegistrySpec}, ::String; prefix::String) at .\file.jl:682
 [13] mktempdir at .\file.jl:680 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [14] clone_or_cp_registries(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.RegistrySpec,1}, ::String) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\Types.jl:911
 [15] clone_or_cp_registries at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\Types.jl:902 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [16] clone_default_registries(::Pkg.Types.Context) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\Types.jl:821
 [17] find_registered!(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{Base.UUID,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\Types.jl:1167
 [18] registry_resolve!(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\Types.jl:727
 [19] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Windows, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\API.jl:146
 [20] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\API.jl:112
 [21] #add#27 at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\API.jl:109 [inlined]
 [22] add(::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\API.jl:109
 [23] do_cmd!(::Pkg.REPLMode.Command, ::REPL.LineEditREPL) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\REPLMode\REPLMode.jl:403
 [24] do_cmd(::REPL.LineEditREPL, ::String; do_rethrow::Bool) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\REPLMode\REPLMode.jl:381
 [25] do_cmd at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\REPLMode\REPLMode.jl:376 [inlined]
 [26] (::Pkg.REPLMode.var"#24#27"{REPL.LineEditREPL,REPL.LineEdit.Prompt})(::REPL.LineEdit.MIState, ::Base.GenericIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}}, ::Bool) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\Pkg\src\REPLMode\REPLMode.jl:542
 [27] #invokelatest#1 at .\essentials.jl:712 [inlined]
 [28] invokelatest at .\essentials.jl:711 [inlined]
 [29] run_interface(::REPL.Terminals.TextTerminal, ::REPL.LineEdit.ModalInterface, ::REPL.LineEdit.MIState) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\REPL\src\LineEdit.jl:2354
 [30] run_frontend(::REPL.LineEditREPL, ::REPL.REPLBackendRef) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\REPL\src\REPL.jl:1055
 [31] run_repl(::REPL.AbstractREPL, ::Any) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.4\REPL\src\REPL.jl:206
 [32] (::Base.var"#764#766"{Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool})(::Module) at .\client.jl:383
 [33] #invokelatest#1 at .\essentials.jl:712 [inlined]
 [34] invokelatest at .\essentials.jl:711 [inlined]
 [35] run_main_repl(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool) at .\client.jl:367
 [36] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at .\client.jl:305
 [37] _start() at .\client.jl:484
```

Does anyone know what I should do here to be able to install packages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows seems to have problem cloning the registry sometimes. You can try to delete `C:\Users\Quinten Cabo\.julia\registries\General` and try again, or (perhaps even better) you could simply `git clone` the registry outside of Julia to that location.

---

In the upcoming Julia 1.5 registries will not use git by default, so hopefully this issue should not be present then.

Comment: Presumably also Windows? We have gotten some reports where it seems like Windows seemingly at random deletes content in those folders, for example https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/issues/2017 where folders A-F was missing.. Not sure what to do about this, but it seems like it is usually fixed if you delete the folder and reinstall it. There are some plans for features to auto-repair things like this but.

Comment: Yes, Windows. And yes, fixed by deleting registries/General, and the doing ]update

Answer (score 1):

I Deleted the .julia\registries\General and then re installed the Package and it worked. So It built the registry again.

It takes a bit of time to rebuild. Have patience.